# Angular 1.3 breaking changes - scope set but reset before $apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

AngularJs 1.3.x, simple controller works but as soon as I re-write it using Typescript and Injection, it fails. If I reference 1.2.x it starts working again.

```
//This works in 1.3.x
scopeApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.username = 'World';
    $scope.sayHello = function () {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
    };
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ssSuuZuGlrypemx3BU5r?p=preview

```
//This DOES NOT works in 1.3.x but does in 1.2.x
//The following code is produced via Typescript:
var MainFeature;
(function (MainFeature) {
    var MainCtrl = (function () {
        function MainCtrl($scope) {
            this.scope = $scope;
            this.name = "Sirar";
            this.message = '';
        }
        MainCtrl.prototype.SetMessage = function () {
            this.message = 'Hello' + this.name;
        };
        return MainCtrl;
    })();
    MainFeature.MainCtrl = MainCtrl;
})(MainFeature || (MainFeature = {}));

scopeApp.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  return new MainFeature.MainCtrl($scope);
}]);
```

Breaking changes docs that have valuable information but didn't help:

1. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration
2. http://ng-learn.org/2014/06/Migration_Guide_from_1-2_to1-3/
3. http://wildermuth.com/2014/11/11/Angular_1_3_and_Breaking_Change_for_Controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the constructor function, not some other function like you did. As I explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880375/controllers-are-created-using-a-factory-function/27881657#27881657) the controller is not created by calling `new`. It's created as follows:

```
instance = Object.create(controllerPrototype);
...
return fn.apply(self, args);
```

The catch is that the return value is not used, but the `instance`. In your case this would mean:

```
instance = Object.create({}); // should be MainCtrl.prototype
...
return fn.apply(self, args);
```

So "MainCtrl" ends up as empty object. You have to do what you should have done in the first place, pass the constructor:

```
scopeApp.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", MainFeature.MainCtrl]);
```

Comment: Please explain how to inject the dependencies into MainFeature.MainCtrl in your answer.   
Is there a way to not use $inject?: http://plnkr.co/edit/NMPXFd67WLXHjhrfync2 
        `scopeApp.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", MainFeature.MainCtrl]);
        MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];`

Comment: @OzBob I don't understand the question. `scopeApp.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", MainFeature.MainCtrl]);` injects `$scope` into the controller. There's nothing else to do.

Comment: I've accepted your answer and understand the 'instance creation' now. Thanks.  I also experimented with just:  
        scopeApp.controller("MainCtrl", [MainFeature.MainCtrl]);
        MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
if I can avoid using "$scope" then when I Uglify/minimized then I'll avoid getting 'string substitution' errors.   Also, as I leave the $inject outside the controller then I leave opportunities for DI'ing mock services in my tests.  Cheers